Remote Permissions require for Non Admin to view Get-HotFix or get-ciminstance results
My domain controllers are all on Powershell Version 5.1 and dotnet 4.8.  I have developed Powershell code for auditing the current state of the Domain Controllers including the following area's.....
OS Information
System information such as physical bios or vm version
CPU
Ram
Local storage
Network Information
Domain
AD OU
AD site
And in this is list of information is get-hotfix to return patching information in the OS Info phase.
When I logon to my Domain Controller with my domain admin account, and run my powershell code locally, I get the expected results of a full audit of the local machine.
When I open powershell as different user using service account from another Domain and run the code I am missing a bunch of info.
What I have found is that the Get-HotFix is returning NULL and breaking the remaining Code.  This information is sort of relevant to my question.  I have confirmed this by moving that section to the end of the list and seeing more data coming thru.
To provide the most basic test scenario, log on to my domain controller and open a PS as different user using the account from the other Domain and execute Get-Hotfix, I get data.  When I use invoke-commmand -computername  -scriptblock {get-hotfix}, the result is NULL.  If I add the domain account to the BuiltIn\Administrator Group, I get results as I did on my first test.
DomainA\Service_Account account provisioning
Member of following DomainB sec groups...
BuiltIn\Distributed Com Users
BuiltIn\Remote Management Users
BuiltIn\Server Operators
Open WMIMgmt and provide Enable and Remote Enable permissions to Root\CIVM2
Open DComCFNG, locate My Comptuter and open permissions, Com Security, and edit Access Permissions and Launch and Activation Permissoins.  Now I clicked the Edit Links button and not the Edit Default of each item.  Added my Distributed Com SG to each allowing all.
As said above, at this point I can get data locally when opening ps as different user with domainA service account.  But when using invoke-command locally, it fails.
Based on the result change when adding to builtin\administrators where the code works correctly, I believe there is another permission which needs to be addressed.
Its been suggested that the UAC may be blocking remote execution and there is a registry key I may want to add to disable UAC.
The other suggestion is to use GPO to add the account or sec group to the Impersonate permissions.
What else am I missing?

You have an HTTP connection with a client and a server.  The server can have one or more routes.  Each routes can have a different set of permissions which can be a users, a groups, or a roles.  Issue like this can be solved by changing the permission at the server.  At client side if you are an admin you could impersonate another user but that isn't really recommended.

This is what JEA is for :)

Does anyone know the related permissions I am missing for this to work?  As suggested by JDweng, I don't really like the impersonate option.  I only stated it as an option as it is a workable solution even if it's not the best option.

Does anyone have any idea?  I know JEA would be a great solution, I am not in a position to push that.  This is what I have, trying to give the proper permissions to a non admin account to remotely pull data, in this case from get-hotfix.

I could really use some help on this.  There has to be a permission to give the account which will allow for this data to be returned when requested remotely.

What other information can I give to provide enough information to get some responses?
